# Group Between Keywords TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Problem**

I import a spread sheet that contains parent group data on the same column as the child. I would like to add extract column for group as show below.

**Create Table**

```
DECLARE @Fruit TABLE
    (
      ProductID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
                    PRIMARY KEY ,
      FruitName NVARCHAR(20) ,
      FruitCost MONEY
    )

INSERT  INTO @fruit
        ( FruitName, FruitCost )
VALUES  ( 'Berry', NULL )
INSERT  INTO @fruit
        ( FruitName, FruitCost )
VALUES  ( 'BlueBerry', 2 )
INSERT  INTO @fruit
        ( FruitName, FruitCost )
VALUES  ( 'StrawBerry', 2 )
INSERT  INTO @fruit
        ( FruitName, FruitCost )
VALUES  ( 'Citrus', NULL )
INSERT  INTO @fruit
        ( FruitName, FruitCost )
VALUES  ( 'Lemon', 2 )
INSERT  INTO @fruit
        ( FruitName, FruitCost )
VALUES  ( 'Orange', 2 )

SELECT  *
FROM    @Fruit
```

**Table Results**

```
ProductID   FruitName            FruitCost
----------- -------------------- ---------------------
1           Berry                NULL
2           BlueBerry            2.00
3           StrawBerry           2.00
4           Citrus               NULL
5           Lemon                2.00
6           Orange               2.00
```

**Required Results**

```
FruitName            FruitCost             FruitGroup
-------------------- --------------------- --------------------
BlueBerry            2.00                  Berry
StrawBerry           2.00                  Berry
Lemon                2.00                  Citrus
Orange               2.00                  Citrus
```

Comment: Is this homework? Also, how do you know that Lemon is a citrus fruit?

Comment: I wish it was hope work. Would like me to change to suitable columns, otherwise if you can't help leave it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select
    f3.FruitName, f3.FruitCost, f.FruitName
from
    @Fruit f
        inner join
    (
        SELECT  *,
        (Select max(productid) from @Fruit f2 where FruitCost is null and ProductID<=f.ProductID) as fgroup
        FROM    @Fruit f
    ) f3
        on f.ProductID = f3.fgroup
where f3.FruitCost is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.FruitName,t.FruitCost,  
(select FruitName from @fruit t2
  where t2.ProductId in 
  (
    select max(t3.ProductId) from 
    @fruit t3 
    where (t3.FruitCost is null) and (t3.ProductId<t.ProductId)
   )

) FruitGroup
from @Fruit t where (t.FruitCost is not null)
```